# Logarithm as Lyapunov function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-theory

I'm dealing with the Lyapunov stability theory. I have an SDE and I want to study the stability of an equilibrium,  the trivial solution. With the function $V(x)=log(x)$ I reach the result that I want...but this function doesn't satisfies the definition of Lyapunov function ($V(0) \ne 0$). There is some theorem that allow to use it?

Answer (score 0):

$V(x) < 0$ for $x \in (0, 1)$ so its not a valid Lyapunov function candidate since $V$ must be strictly positiv in a region that contains the origin (and equal to $0$ at the origin).